# jQM Difference between $.post and $.ajax and I get error with $.post

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-mobile

In my hybrid app (using jQM as framework), I try to retrieve data from server.

I tried both **$.post** and **$.ajax** method.

With **$.ajax**, I can access the return data with **"data[0].name"**.

With **$.post** and exact same return data, when I try access the data with **"data[0].name"** I get **"undefined"**.

**My code that works ($.ajax) and show me correct data:**

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#restaurantList', function() {
    $.ajax({
    url: "http://mydomain.com/api/restaurant/allstate/allcuisine",
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
        alert(data[0].restaurant_id);
    }
    });
    });
```

**My code that does not work ($.post) and give me "undefined":**

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#restaurantList', function() {
    $.post("http://mydomain.com/api/restaurant/allstate/allcuisine",
    function(data){
        alert(data[0].restaurant_id);
    });
    });
```

Why is that? There is a reason I need to use **$.post** but I just unable to access the data. I have check the return JSON, both method return the exact same data.

Please point me the difference between these two and why I get **"undefined"** from **$.post** method. Thank you.

Comment: There are different default values passed to `$.ajax` by `$.post`, so you need to show your Ajax code in full. `$.post` is shorthand for `$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: url,
  data: data,
  success: success,
  dataType: dataType
});` Also check the return data using a free tool, like Fiddler2, as you may simply be getting a server error.

Comment: Hi @TrueBlueAussie, thanks for your comment. I have added my example code that I tested with. Please advice, thank you.

Comment: Have you checked the traffic (use the F12 Chrome debug tools or install Fiddler2)?

Comment: Traffic mean the inbound data? I'm using XDK development tool from Intel. It has built in debugging tool.

Comment: Inbound data, yes. You need to see if the response is different (not defaulting to `json` etc).

Comment: But the inbound data is JSON. On server php I give: echo json_encode($restaurant);

Comment: I have checked using the build-in tool. The inbound data are exactly the same. Just can't figure out why it give me "undefined" when using $.post.

Answer (score 1):

For $.post to work properly with JSON return data. dataType have to be specified.

According to jQM document:

> dataType Type: String The type of data expected from the server.
>   Default: Intelligent Guess (xml, json, script, text, html).

But it's Intelligent Guess doesn't seem to be intelligent enough.

For this to work, add in "json", example below:

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#restaurantList', function() {
    $.post("http://mydomain.com/api/restaurant/allstate/allcuisine",
    function(data){
        alert(data[0].restaurant_id);
    }, "json");
    });
```